# updated page og tag to update in facebook

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags

On my website there is a page that a user is able to update with new images and description. I'm pulling this information into the og tags so that when it gets shared on social media it shows up. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the user update their info on my website and then when he pastes the same link into facebook to have a new thumbnail for the attached link. I know about the facebook debug tool, but it is too much to ask from my users.

Is there any solution to this? The only thing that I came up with is to attach a random number at the end of the link (or a version number based on the number of updates).

Thanks

Comment: Your solution is actually pretty good

Comment: Is it possible to keep the link intact so that I don't get duplicates in SEO. I haven't got a the "canonical" links sorted yet.

Comment: You can block those pages with robots.txt since they probably have little to do with SEO

Comment: So lets say that the user's page is .com/profile/my-new-car/1, then he updates to .com/profile/my-new-car/2;/3;/4 etc when the different links are shared it would be hard to measure the shareability of the /my-new-car/. Also the /1;/2;/3 will be indexed by google as different pages since i don't have canonical links. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: use '#' instead of '/' and use robots.txt to block google from reading  this page or reading this page + '#'.  The _best_ way to do it is probably server side with a different URL for each user. This way they can go back there, share it etc'